# How to find all the clients that connected from specific hostname in ChannelGroup

Tags: java, netty

I am learning about the netty framework and Google protobuf, so now I am writing some simple server and client applications.

I wrote a server based on the SecureChat example that come from netty and I want to write a method that return all the channels that connected from a specific ip (no matter what port).
I have a ChannelGroup that holds all the connected channels and I thought about using the write method - write(Object message, SocketAddress remoteAddress), but in the SocketAddress class I have to insert port.

So I thought about other ways but the only way I found working is using a for loop, but there is another ways? Some way that will give me better performance?

Thanks, BBLN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your own ChannelGroup implementation which supports this. For this you could have a Map of Channels that are using the InetAddress of the Channel as key. So you will be able to lookup all Channels by IP in a fast way.